# Can you help me understand this Node Analyzing Method in Thevenin Norton Circuits

Tags: current, thevenin, norton, mesh-analysis, nodal-analysis

[image]

This is the circuit, and the node method solution is:

[image]

Where did 280 come from? why is there two Vt/60 ? Please help me

Comment: I think solution is incorrect! Because 1st equation doesn't satisfy for Vt=10v

Comment: The solution is correct. The KCL equation is incorrect. The constraint equation is correct.

Comment: Thank you everybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where did 280 come from? why is there two Vt/60 ?

As chomeyama said, the solution is correct. The KCL equation is incorrect. The constraint equation is correct. So just ignore the equation with which you have doubts.

Here's how to obtain the correct equation and the result. Redraw the circuit as shown below:

[image: Circuit diagram]

Apply KCL at the node of \$v_\text{T}\$:

\$ -\dfrac{v_\text{T} - (-160 \, i_\Delta)}{80} - \dfrac{v_\text{T}}{80} - \dfrac{v_\text{T}}{40} + 1 = 0 \tag*{}\$

\$ \implies -\dfrac{1}{80} v_\text{T} - \dfrac{160}{80} i_\Delta - \dfrac{1}{80} v_\text{T} - \dfrac{1}{40} v_\text{T} + 1 = 0 \tag*{}\$

\$ \implies \left( -\dfrac{1}{80} - \dfrac{1}{80} - \dfrac{1}{40} \right) v_\text{T} - 2 \, i_\Delta + 1 = 0 \tag*{}\$

\$ \implies -\dfrac{1}{20} v_\text{T} - 2 \, i_\Delta = -1 \tag 1\$

Constraint equation for the dependent source: express the controlling variable (\$i_\Delta\$) in terms of the nodal voltages. Applying Ohm's law in the resistor of \$\text{40 } \Omega\$:

\$i_\Delta = \dfrac{v_\text{T}}{40} \tag 2\$

Now we have two equations (*(1)* and *(2)*) and two unknowns (\$v_\text{T}\$ and \$i_\Delta\$), so we can solve the eqs. to find the unknowns. Substituting eq. *(2)* in *(1)* yields:

\$ -\dfrac{1}{20} v_\text{T} - 2 \left( \dfrac{v_\text{T}}{40} \right) = -1 \tag*{}\$

\$ \implies -\dfrac{1}{20} v_\text{T} - \dfrac{1}{20} v_\text{T} = -1 \tag*{}\$

\$ \implies -\dfrac{1}{10} v_\text{T} = -1 \tag*{}\$

\$ \implies v_\text{T} = 10 \tag*{}\$

The following simulation proves the previous result (please ignore the voltage source in series with the resistor of \$\text{40 } \Omega\$, it has 0 V so it doesn't affect the circuit):

[image: Simulation]

Answer (score 1):

The answer is correct, vt = 10 V, but the equation is wrong.
That should be (vt + 160 i) / 80 + vt / 80 + vt / 40 - 1 = 0.
The circuit can be simplified by Thevenin Norton theorem and that may the intention of who made this problem.